# misunderstanding the global operator overload rule

Tags: c++, g++, operator-overloading

I found the [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x88tzx0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) below that says that

```
 If an operator can be used as either a unary or a binary 
 operator (&, *, +, and -), you can overload each use separately.
```

I am working with g++ in Linux and I tried the following and it didn't compile.

```
int operator+ (const int a,const int b){
   std::cout << "MINE"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}

int main(){
   char c='c';
   std::cout << c+2 << std::endl;
}
```

The error says

```
error: ‘int operator+(int, int)’ must have an argument 
of class or enumerated type
```

I was willing to play and see in action the Integer Promotion Rules.

Am I doing something wrong or that URL is valid only for MS or I misunderstood the promotion rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message indirectly tells you what you need to know -- you are not permitted to overload operators (binary or unary) that act only on built-in types.

For a user-defined type `T`, you can separately overload binary + (for example by `T operator+(T lhs, T rhs)`) and unary + (for example by `T operator+(T t)`). You could also define `operator+(T lhs, int rhs)`, but you can't overload addition of two integers.

Comment: Hi Steve! Thanks for your response ( I thank with a bit of delay )!
Eh!Eh! These are the kind of things that makes me say 'back-to-basic'!!!

Answer (score 1):

Example is incorrect since
n3337 13.5/6

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have
> at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
> enumeration.